# getting linker errors symbol(s) not found for architecture i368

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios6

I am using iFrameExtractor it get compiled successfully on iphone device but when i am using it on simulator it show following error.

```
 "_av_dict_set", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor initWithVideo:usesTcp:] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avcodec_open2", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor initWithVideo:usesTcp:] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[VideoFrameExtractor setupAudioDecoder] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avformat_close_input", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor dealloc] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avformat_find_stream_info", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor initWithVideo:usesTcp:] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avformat_open_input", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor initWithVideo:usesTcp:] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

can any one help me out with clear step by step solution. As I am new to ios.

Thank you
Chandra Pr.

Answer (score 0):

looks like its not finding the required ffmpeg libraries, might be because your libs are compiled for device but looks like you are trying to build on simulator.